# How to select a row after group by unioned tables?

Tags: sql, hiveql

I need to select the newest row from two tables, two tables have the same schema

Table A and Table B is the same schema, like this:

Table A :

```
user_id, time_stamp, order_id

1,20190101,100

2,20190103,201

3,20190102,300

5,20180209,99
```

Table B:

```
user_id, time_stamp, order_id

1,20190102,101

2,20190101,200

3,20190103,305

4,20190303,900
```

I want the output is A union B, then select the newer row of a user, order by time_stamp:

output should be:

```
1,20190102,101

2,20190103,201

3,20190103,305

4,20190303,900

5,20180209,99
```

How to write this SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can write as following sample query [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=908888d4bc1f42438fac03e5f8c28315)

```
with unionedTable as (
select * from tableA
union
select * from tableB)
,newerUsersTable as (
select  distinct on (u.user_id)u.*
from unionedTable u
order by u.user_id, u.time_stamp desc

)select * from newerUsersTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is using `FULL OUTER JOIN` among two tables, and then using `UNION [ALL]` for returning data set. So, consider the following `SELECT` statement with `WITH` clause :

```
with a( user_id, time_stamp, order_id ) as
(
 select 1,20190101,100 union all
 select 2,20190103,201 union all    
 select 3,20190102,300 union all    
 select 5,20180209,99  
), b( user_id, time_stamp, order_id ) as
(
 select 1,20190102,101 union all
 select 2,20190101,200 union all    
 select 3,20190103,305 union all    
 select 4,20190303,900 
), c as
(
select a.user_id as user_id_a, a.time_stamp as time_stamp_a, a.order_id as order_id_a,
       b.user_id as user_id_b, b.time_stamp as time_stamp_b, b.order_id as order_id_b
  from a full outer join b
    on a.user_id = b.user_id 
), d as
(
select user_id_a, time_stamp_a, order_id_a  
  from c
 where coalesce(time_stamp_b,time_stamp_a) <= time_stamp_a 
union all 
select user_id_b, time_stamp_b, order_id_b 
  from c
 where time_stamp_b >= coalesce(time_stamp_a,time_stamp_b)
)
select user_id_a as user_id, time_stamp_a as time_stamp, order_id_a as order_id
  from d
 order by user_id_a;

user_id time_stamp  order_id
1       20190102    101
2       20190103    201
3       20190103    305
4       20190303    900
5       20180209    99
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a74159a10344af981073ef0d50362a8b)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use Group by(user_id) to show all user_id

Use max(time_stamp) get the newer row of user

```
SELECT aa.* from (select * from a union SELECT * from b ) aa 
JOIN 
(select user_id,max(time_stamp) as new_time
from (select * from a union SELECT * from b ) u
group by u.user_id) bb
on bb.new_time=aa.time_stamp and bb.user_id=aa.user_id
order by aa.user_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/808cde/6)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
select user_id, time_stamp, order_id
from (select ab.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by time_stamp desc) as seqnum
      from (select a.* from a union all
            select b.* from b
           ) ab
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1;
```